# Why doesn't super.__new__ need argument but instance.__new__ needs?

Tags: python, new-operator, super

Trying to understand `super` and `__new__`

Here goes my code:

```
class Base(object):
    def __new__(cls,foo):
        if cls is Base:
            if foo == 1:
                #  return Base.__new__(Child) complains not enough arguments
                return Base.__new__(Child,foo)
            if foo == 2:
                # how does this work without giving foo?
                return super(Base,cls).__new__(Child)  
        else:
            return super(Base,cls).__new__(cls,foo)

    def __init__(self,foo):
        pass 
class Child(Base):
    def __init__(self,foo):
        Base.__init__(self,foo)    
a = Base(1)  # returns instance of class Child
b = Base(2)  # returns instance of class Child
c = Base(3)  # returns instance of class Base
d = Child(1)  # returns instance of class Child
```

Why doesn't `super.__new__` need an argument while `__new__` needs it?

Python: 2.7.11

Comment: For the same reason why `object.__new__` doesn't need a `foo` but `Base.__new__` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super().__new__` is not the same function as `Base.__new__`. `super().__new__` is `object.__new__`. `object.__new__` doesn't require a `foo` argument, but `Base.__new__` does.

```
>>> Base.__new__
<function Base.__new__ at 0x000002243340A730>
>>> super(Base, Base).__new__
<built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x00007FF87AD89EC0>
>>> object.__new__
<built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x00007FF87AD89EC0>
```

What may be confusing you is this line:

```
return super(Base,cls).__new__(cls, foo)
```

This calls `object.__new__(cls, foo)`. That's right, it passes a `foo` argument to `object.__new__` even though `object.__new__` doesn't need it. This is allowed in python 2, but would crash in python 3. It would be best to remove the `foo` argument from there.

Comment: And one more question is how could we possibly refer `Child` object in `return super(Base,cls).__new__(Child) ` when `Child` class is defined below the `Base`? I mean `Base` should ideally not have `Child` in its scope i thought? Is that because of `Super` having a super power :) ?

Comment: @AnveshYalamarthy No, that doesn't require a super power. It works for the same reason why two functions can call each other even though one is defined after the other - by the time the code is executed, the `Child` class has already been created. If you try `a = Base(1)` *before* you define the `Child` class then you will indeed get an error.